# Is Optimistic-Locking absolutely safe?

Tags: optimistic-locking

when using optimistic-locking strategy, it can solve concurrency problem like below:

```
| the first transaction started        |
|                                      |  
| select a row                         |
|                                      |  the second transaction started
| update the row with version checking |
|                                      |  select the same row 
| commit txn                           |
|                                      |  update the row with version checking
|                                      |  
|                                      |  rolls back because version is dirty
```

But what if in the extremely rare cases if the update in the second transaction is after the udpate in the first transaction but before the the transaction commit?

```
| the first transaction started        |
|                                      |  the second transaction started
| select a row                         |
|                                      |  select the same row 
| update the row with version checking |
|                                      |  update the row with version checking
| commit txn                           |
|                                      |  rolls back because version is dirty // will it?
|                                      |  
|                                      |
```

I made an experiment that the update in the second transaction could not read the 'dirty' version because the first transaction had not been committed yet. Will the second transaction fail in this case?

Comment: @Adam Arold Thank you for telling me this aphorism. I google it `cause I am not a native english speaker :) But will the optimistic-locking strategy work in the case I mentioned?

Comment: If it is really optimistic, how come you use transaction feature? Update will fail by itself without any need of rollback.

Comment: @tia Maybe in the example, it's ok with or without transactions.But sometimes I need to rollback other changes(e.g. maybe some inserts to a sub-table ) to the database

Comment: Sorry that was a reference to Star Wars and I had to mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say in your question what database system you're actually using, so I don't know the details of your system.

But in any case, under an optimistic locking system, a process cannot just check the row versions when it performs the update statement, because of exactly the problem you are worried about.

For fully serializable, isolated transactions, each process must atomically check the row versions of all the rows it examined and modified, at commit time.  So in your second scenario, the right-hand process will not detect a conflict until it tries to commit (a step which you did not include for the right-hand process).  When it tries to commit, it will detect the conflict and roll back.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.We use Oracle 10g in production environment, the isolation level is read committed.

Comment: Will it really fail when it tries to commit. I mean it will not throw exception when the number check fails when using optimistic-locking, it just update 0 rows instead and developer throws an exception when the row affected equals to 0.

Comment: Maybe I can make another experiment, sleep the thread after the update sql is executed but before committing the transaction and update the same row in another thread then wake the first thread up.

Comment: The result is that it throws an exception telling optimistic-locking failure when it tries to commit the transaction. The result is based on Hibernate. But if I remove the transactional, it will pass with dirty update. So the transactional feature is very important in this case. I will give it another try using iBATIS later(check optimistic-locking programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

As you've already discovered, Optimistic Locking is subject to [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race condition: before the commit decision and the actual commit, there is a short time window during which another transaction can modify the data.

To make Optimistic Locking 100% safe, you have to make sure that the second transaction waits until the first transaction commits and only then makes a version check:

[image]

You can achieve this by acquiring a row-level (select for update) lock prior to the update statement.

jOOQ [does](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/optimistic-locking/) that for you. In Hibernate, you have to lock the row manually:

```
var pessimisticRead = new LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
session.buildLockRequest(pessimisticRead).lock(entity);
```

Beware that you can't reproduce that annoying TOCTOU race condition in Hibernate on a single VM. Hibernate will smoothly resolve this thanks to the shared Persistent Context. When transactions run on different VMs, Hibernate can't help, and you'll have to add extra locking.

Comment: I tested this with MySQL 8.0. The first update puts a lock on the row, causing the second update to wait until the first transaction is committed.

Comment: In postgres if we combine OPTIMISTIC LOCK with REPEATABLE_READ isolation level, we can get rid of this issue. In Mysql you should use SERIALIZABLE given the not fully compliant way it implements REPEATABLE_READ level.

Comment: Such a time window does not exist. Normally optimistic locking is realised in a way, at least Hibernate and eclipselink do it in such a way that the check and update of the version take place in one update command, together with updaten the other data. So this is atomic.
The update locks the row for other transactions until commit or rollback.
Database locks take place in the database and have nothing to do with Hibernate on multiple VMs.