# When would you use Hibernate optimistic lock over postgres serializable isolation level?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, optimistic-locking

Good day , I understand what is a serializable isolation level and how it differs from `REPEATABLE READ` in Postgres. Serializable transaction is able to detect read write cycles so only the first commit will succeed .

With this in mind, does it make sense to use `Hibernate's` optimistic locking based on row versioning  ? The row versioning will behave in exactly the same manner, if version column was updated then Java exception will be thrown which will rollback the transaction. Moreover, according to [Postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hibernate_oplocks) , the trigger has to be created if some updates were done out of application level code (like plain sql query ran by psql). So in my humble opinion , Serializable level is a drop in replacement for Optimistic locking , is it so or there are some use cases where you would prefer Optimistic locking instead ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't mix up `REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE`: the latter is stronger than the former, and the former does not incur additional performance costs. `REPEATABLE READ` is enough for optimistic locking.

I would normally prefer optimistic locking with database techniques, as this will be cheaper. There is, however, one case in which I would prefer optimistic locking on the application side: if the resulting database transaction would take long.

With `REPEATABLE READ`, you have to perform the `SELECT` and the final `UPDATE` in the same database transaction. Now transactions have to be short for the database to work well, so if there is for example a user interaction involved, using `REPEATABLE READ` transactions would be a non-starter.

If you want to know what is bad about long `REPEATABLE READ` transactions:

1. they hold locks, potentially blocking concurrent activity indefinitely long (imagine you want to run an `ALTER TABLE` in this database)
2. they prevent the progress of autovacuum, thereby bloating your tables

Comment: They are not actual locks right ? docs: row might have already been updated by another concurrent transaction by the time it is found. In this case, the repeatable read transaction will wait for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is still in progress). If the first updater rolls back, then its effects are negated and the repeatable read transaction can proceed with updating the originally found row. But if the first updater commits (and actually updated or deleted the row, not just locked it) then the repeatable read transaction will be rolled back with the message"

Comment: @GionJh Any long running transaction that modifies data holds locks for a long time. But what causes the serialization error are not the locks.

Comment: Yes makes sense so the "the repeatable read transaction will wait for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back" is implemented with locks.

Answer (score 1):

One use case would be Long conversations, see here: https://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/)

In this case though in order to avoid lost updates, ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888951/is-optimistic-locking-absolutely-safe.)) you should use Optimistic locking in addition to `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level if using `postgres`, in mysql I think `SERIALIZABLE` would be needed.